# As funções remove() e rename() não funcionam!

Tags: c

Olá, estou fazendo um programa em tem uma parte dele que deve excluir um cliente e os dados do tal que estão em um arquivo .txt! até ai tudo bem, eu crio um novo arquivo com um nome diferente que copia todos os clientes que estavam no outro arquivo, menos o cliente a ser excluído! más apos ter feito isso eu preciso apagar o primeiro arquivo e mudar o nome do segundo para o nome do primeiro!

Ai eu dei uma pesquisada e encontrei essas duas funções que prometem apagar e renomear arquivos, acontece ao tentar usa-las elas nem apagam e nem renomeiam os arquivos já tentei muita ciosa, mas nada deu certo, inclusive quando eu vou ver a saída das funções, ao invés de retornarem zero retornam -1. Se alguém puder ajudar eu ficaria muito grato!

Desde já agradeço!

```
void copia_arquivo(FILE *file1, FILE *file2, char cpf[15])

{

char confirma_nome2[15];
char confirma_ultimoNome2[15];
char confirma_dataNasc2[11];
char confirma_cpf2[15];
int confirma_numero2;

 while (fscanf(file1, "%s %s  %s %i %s", confirma_nome2, confirma_ultimoNome2, confirma_dataNasc2, &confirma_numero2, confirma_cpf2) != EOF)
{
    if (strstr(cpf, confirma_cpf2) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(file2, "%s %s  %s %i %s\n", confirma_nome2, confirma_ultimoNome2, confirma_dataNasc2, confirma_numero2, confirma_cpf2);
    }
}
fclose(file1);
fclose(file2);
remove("clientes\\client.txt");
rename("clientes\\client2.txt", "clientes\\client.txt");
}
```

Comment: Criar um novo arquivo e remover o antigo não é uma boa solução. Melhor é mesmo abrir o arquivo normalmente para escrita(sem ser `append`) e escrever diretamente a informação que pretende.

Comment: acontece que oque eu quero nao é escrever e sim apagar, apagar os dados do cliente! acho que nao tem outra forma de fazer que nao seja esta.

Comment: Se voce esta em ambiente Windows tem que passar o caminho completo dos arquivos nas funcoes `remove` e `rename`.

Comment: Tem sempre mil e uma formas diferentes de fazer, e essa que optou não é das melhores mesmo. Melhor seria ler os clientes do arquivo para memória numa lista/vetor de clientes, e remover ou ler apenas os que interessam (não lendo/armazenando os que quer remover). Depois volta a escreve-los no mesmo arquivo, que os removidos já não serão escritos de novo.